# Why aren't leading edge root extensions used on airliners?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, airliner, high-lift-device

Why aren't *[leading-edge root extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading-edge_extension#Leading-edge_root_extension)* used on airliners?

Wouldn't they result in shorter wings and smaller slats?

[image]

Image source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Leadingedgeextensions_annotated.svg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leading edge extensions like [slats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading-edge_slats) are used in airliners. Most of these are controlled ones, so as to improve low speed characteristics.

[image: A-319]

By Adrian Pingstone ([Arpingstone](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Arpingstone)) - Own work, Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=4761104

The dog tooth extensions were used in some older airliners like the [Ilyushin Il-62](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-62) and the [Vickers Super VC-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-62), he reason being the requirement to [reduce drag](http://www.vc10.net/Memories/Trialstribulations.html).

[image: Il- 62]

By Sergey Lysenko - [File:Air-to-air with a Russian Air Force Ilyushin Il-62M.jpg](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Air-to-air_with_a_Russian_Air_Force_Ilyushin_Il-62M.jpg) on Wikimedia Commons, originally published on http://russianplanes.net/id164205, CC BY-SA 4.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=40618026

The other leading edge extensions like LERX (and even dog tooth) are mostly found in high performance combat aircraft as these increase the stall angle and improve maneuverability; these are not the typical concerns in the commercial airliners. In airliners, [vortex generators are used](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/23234/9731) for preventing separation at low speed (high aoa).