# Is a 20% forced transition in xfoil similar to adding a vg?

Tags: aerodynamics

Is a 20% forced transition etc. in xfoil similar to adding a vg?

I understand a 20% forced transition in xfoil, is tripping the boundary layer from laminar to turbulent.  Isn't that what a VG does?

A classic shaped naca foil like 2415, has a max cl of 1.5.  I understand that vg's usually add a cl of about 0.5-0.7.

So... if I force a transition to turbulent at about 15-20% of chord in xfoil, shouldn't the max cl of a classic foil go up from 1.5 to about 2?

It doesn't....?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

It is more like putting a [turbulator](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/32557/how-do-blow-holes-compare-to-other-means-of-tripping-the-boundary-layer/32562#32562) (such as a trip wire) there. [Vortex generators](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13876/what-is-a-vortex-generator) will create a small vortex (hence the name) which puts much more energy into the boundary layer. XFOIL has no mechanism for simulating [vortex generators](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23233/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-small-fins-on-top-of-the-wing-surface-of-boeing-aircr/23235#23235).

Adding a forced turbulent transition will weaken the boundary layer downstream of its natural transition point, so it will tolerate less pressure rise. I assume you put them on the upper side: Now the airfoil will stall a bit earlier (at a lower angle of attack and lift coefficient).

15-20% is an unusual location for a turbulator, especially on the upper side. Their best location depends on the Reynolds number and the pressure distribution. On gliders, they make most sense on the lower side at around 80% of chord. On the upper side they might help a bit in part of the polar when placed at around 50%.

Comment: Ok great. Can one model a working slat in Xfoil?  How about Javafoil?

Comment: For a multi-element airfoil there is [MSES](http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/mses/). If you need to do the job of a van, don't pick a bicycle.