# Does opening of emergency doors over wings, lead to automatic lowering of the aircraft's wings?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing

When the emergency doors over the wings are opened do the wings automatically lower themselves, to allow passengers to slide and reach the ground? Or does the pilot have to do it from the cockpit?

Comment: I initially read "lowering of gear" and I was actually looking for an answer. then I realized thet you are asking about **lowering the wings**!? Where have you seen/heard of such a thing?

Comment: I saw an image on the airline safety card, which displayed how people are supposed to alight the aircraft over the wings. It showed the rear wings / flaps are completely lowered, over which people slide and come to the ground

Comment: ah, lowering "the wings" gives quite a different mental image than "lowering the flaps"

Comment: `does the wings outside automatically lower themselves, to allow passengers to slide and reach the ground. Or does the pilot have to do it from the cockpit` - bad assumption.  Neither is true.  Do you mean lower the flaps?

Comment: @Simon I mean both

Comment: The wings cannot be moved, either automatically, or from the cockpit.  What do you mean "both"?

Comment: Although this seems to be a strange question for those of us with aviation knowledge, I don't agree with the close votes - it's still an on-topic, valid (if slightly obvious to most of us) question, which is clear to understand and also has a single clear answer. Therefore it does, I believe, still fit as an Aviation.SE question.

Comment: @JonStory  The close vote is not for "off topic".  I've asked Firee for clarification of flaps vs wings which has not been given.  It is often the case that non-aviators start with a misconception and it is not at all clear to me that the OP does not believe that the wings themselves move.

Comment: Regardless, the question in the current format is a clear, valid question.

Comment: @Simon: `The wings cannot be moved, either automatically, or from the cockpit. What do you mean "both"?` How would I know the wings cannot be moved, hence I asked the question. Also, if you read my comments, my assumption is based on the image of the safety card, in which the wing had almost touched the ground.

Comment: I did a [quick search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=airplane+safety+cards&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIstW7vZzWxwIVClwUCh33Dgns&biw=2560&bih=1336#imgrc=_) through airplane safety cards and could not find any that depict the wings lowered. Do you perhaps know what airplane (or even airline - allowing us to narrow down type) you were flying with when you saw this?

Comment: @Jamiec: It was Jet Airways, aircraft was B767

Comment: @Firee My point was in the question I asked - "do you mean lower the flaps?"   People often ask questions in comments and it's always useful to answer them.  If you don't know what flaps are either, just say so and people will fill in the blanks.  Your question., paraphrased, asks "automatic or from the cockpit".  You asked a "this or that" question to which the answer is neither.  I've edited your question to assist as I now assume you do mean flaps and retracted my close vote.

Comment: Simon, there is still absolutely no reason to assume the asker means flaps, as the safety card they saw may have been, for example, a crash landed, low wing aircraft with its gear raised. And regardless, your close request was unwarranted with the original (valid) question. You've now potentially changed the meaning of the question entirely.

Comment: I have to second Jon Story, if the OP meant wings we should not change it only because it makes no sense to us.

Comment: @JonStory I am simply trying to help the OP.  If the question is "do the wings move automatically or from the cockpit", the only correct answer is "neither" and the question makes no sense.  How will it help future visitors or people searching? It might also help the OP to understand the difference between wings and flaps. I'm just trying to help but I can't get excited about it.  Just undo the edit if you do.  BTW, I am as entitled as anyone, in a community curated site to close.  Just as you are not to or to re-open.  I might consider yours unwarranted but that's why we have votes.

Comment: The question makes perfect sense. Sometimes 'no' is the correct answer. In fact the 'best' answer would probably be to say neither, then point out that his impression may have come from either flaps (eg most aircraft would typically lower flaps before crash landing) or a gear up landing. Answer the question better rather than changing the question to match the answer you'd like to give

Comment: @JonStory I have no plan to add any answer.  And my comment which started the nonsense storm did exactly as you propose. Please read my first comment again.  As I say, feel free to undo the edit.

Comment: Just a reminder from the tour: _This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat._ and _Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer._

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Wings are static.

The wings do not move in response to emergency door opening. There is no requirement regarding position of flaps, in most cases involving an emergency evacuation after landing, flaps are likely to be extended, but I don't think this is guaranteed.

### Evacuation assistance

On commercial transport aircraft, there are marked routes on the wing for passengers and, if the exit point is more than 6ft from the ground, there are self-inflating slides that allow passengers to reach the ground.

[image]
<sup>Image from [video by "Airline_Alex"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Xu9XRHyGNc)</sup>

---

### Evacuation on water

The inflated slides also work as life-rafts in the event that the aircraft comes to rest in water and has to be evacuated. Generally this applies only to slides at main exits, over-wing exits have slides that are not designed to be used in this way.

[image] <sup>[US 1549](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_Airways_Flight_1549)</sup>

---

### Regulations

The [regulations in the USA](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=9ddb4757a29c0e7ab8c4dcfacc93c21b&r=APPENDIX&n=14y3.0.1.1.8.13.3.6.26) say

> Each passenger-carrying landplane emergency exit (other than over-the-wing) that is more that 6 feet from the ground with the airplane on the ground and the landing gear extended must have an approved means to assist the occupants in descending to the ground.

The manufacturer must demonstrate that they can evacuate all passengers and crew to the ground within 90 seconds using only half the emergency exits.

This applies to aircraft capable of carrying more than 44 passengers.

---

### Variations in arrangements by aircraft

Not all aircraft need overwing exits and slides. Here are some B757 variants

[image]
[image]
[image]
<sup>From [CRJ Resets](http://www.crjresets.ca/z-Mcon/Hard2Find/B757/757_rr/airplane_general/doors_and_windows.htm)</sup>

### Boeing 737

As commenters have noted, the 737 does not have self-inflating slides for its over-wing exits.

[image]
<sup>[Pessini](http://www.psafetycards.com/qs.htm)</sup>

The 737 system does not always work very well

> Passengers climbed onto both wings, which
>   were slippery due to the rain, but were able to see
>   the markings indicating the direction of movement. It
>   was difficult to see the ground in the dark and some
>   passengers were not aware that they should slide down
>   the flap surfaces. Others expected to find an escape
>   slide. On the left wing, some passengers slid down
>   onto the ground and assisted others. On the right
>   wing, fewer people slid down to the ground, while
>   others re‑entered the cabin and exited it using door
>   escape slides when it was apparent that there were no
>   visible signs of danger.

- from [AAIB report](https://www.gov.uk/aaib-reports/boeing-737-804-g-gdfj-19-october-2012)

Comment: Do all commercial airlines have over-wing slides?

Comment: @Firee I believe that _every_ exit door will have a slide attached so that if the plane makes an emergency landing, passengers & crew will be able to safely make it to the ground - it can be a pretty significant drop.

Comment: @Federico; Thanks, that video depicted it very well. However, isn't there a risk of the blast from the engines in this scenario?

Comment: @Firee It is standard practice to shut off the engines after an emergency landing (assuming they're still running after everything stops moving). Generally the cabin crew will not begin the evacuation until that has been accomplished as having your passengers survive an emergency landing only to be swallowed up or blown away by the engines makes for really bad press.

Comment: @Firee jetblast (and passengers getting sucked in) is an issue with the other exits as well. that's why they get shut down.

Comment: B737 does **not** have slides for its overwing exits and passengers are expected to slide down the flaps, which is I suppose the reason for the question.

Comment: Note that shutting down the engines may not always be possible. In the QF32 accident, shrapnel from the exploded engine severed the control lines to the still running one, and as a result, with no control inputs to tell it otherwise, the FADEC kept it running at the last power settings. The fire brigade had to shut it down by shooting foam directly into the intake.

Comment: @JanHudec: You are right. If you read my comments in the question, I do mention that the image on the safety card did not show any slide.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: The QF32 accident is really an interesting read. I wonder, couldn't they have evacuated the passengers from the other side of the aircraft, where the engines had completely stopped, or is it a danger to be anywhere near a plane with one of its engines running

Comment: @Firee: They probably could have evacuated, if they really wanted to. But why? The aircraft had safely landed, all fires were extinguished. Evacuating via the slides pretty much *always* leads to broken bones, so that's definitely worse than sitting around for an hour. They could have brought airstairs to the port side exits and evacuated the passengers directly into shuttle busses, making sure nobody wanders around the airplane, but still, why risk it? They were probably sitting there drinking coffee, feasting on delicious airline food, and there was no real danger.

Comment: @Firee: Actually, I just re-watched the episode, and it turns out, they *did* evacuate with the outboard engine still running. The reason they didn't evacuate before was that the aircraft was still leaking fuel onto the runway, not because of the running engine. They evacuated via stairs (which is much safer than slides) as soon as all the fuel had been covered in firefighting foam. In the archive footage you can see firefighters walk around the aircraft quite close to the engine while attempting to "shoot it out".

Comment: @JörgWMittag : I just watched it too on YT. What I was amazed, was the ability of the engine to withstand so much water spray and still keep running. They explained that the engine is designed to withstand torrential rains. Just curious as to how much amount of water/rain could those engines withstand.

Comment: @Firee: You should ask another question, engine water ingestion is not sufficiently related to this Q about over-wing-exits. Also ... [chat].

Answer (score 9):

There are *no transport aircraft where the wings would be movable*.

However if you meant *flaps*, the question would make sense.

In most aircraft the overwing exits are equipped with inflatable slides that inflate aft over the wing trailing edge (see the image in the other answer). However in some aircraft it is indeed intended that the escaping persons will slide down the flaps, most notably on Boeing 737:

[image: Boeing 737-800 evacuation procedures]
(copied from [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/2461/524), the original [source](http://flight72.storenvy.com/collections/132463-safety-cards/products/120964-delta-airlines-boeing-737-800-safety-card) seems unfortunately dead)

No, the flaps *don't move automatically*. The pilots have to extend them. Worse, the flaps require power to move and they move rather slowly, so they may not extend all the way due to lack of time or failure of the necessary systems.

I've seen some incident report involving evacuation where it was mentioned that the flaps were not extended all the way down due to lack of time, but I don't remember enough details to find the reference now.

Comment: The dead source is from [here](http://flight72.storenvy.com) where they have a 737-700/-800 flight safety card [currently for sale](http://flight72.storenvy.com/products/12243051-southwest-airlines-boeing-737-700-800-aircraft-emergency-safety-card-09-14).