# What are static discharges for on an airliner?

Tags: airliner, wing, aircraft-systems

[image]
I have never noticed these on any boeing planes before, so why are these on airbus a320 series and not on the boeing 737 and also what are they for?

Comment: They are static dischargers. See http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2720/what-are-these-things-hanging-off-the-trailing-edge-of-the-wing

Comment: This [meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) explains how to upload screenshots, it should help you

Comment: I think the more interesting thing you got a good picture of in that shot is the nice yellow anchor point for use in over-wing evacuations ([see here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2456/what-are-these-hooks-on-the-a320s-wing-used-for))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to tell by the picture, but they look like `static wicks.` See [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2720/what-are-these-things-hanging-off-the-trailing-edge-of-the-wing?lq=1) question.

Comment: Those are static wicks to dissipate electrical charge which can build up doe to atmospheric friction on he airframe.